# Feynman Path integrals in space with holes in it

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-geometry, curvature, path-integral, topology

Feynman Path Integrals are a way of calculating the wave function of quantum mechanics. It usually integrates every possible path through all of space. I wonder if there is any study of Feynman path integrals through a space with holes in it - with regions of space excluded from the integration process. More specifically, I'm wondering about points or regions of space where the amplitude must be zero. I assume that a point or region that is exclude from the path integral means that the amplitude will be zero there.

I've heard described elsewhere that a space with holes in it can result in curvature in that space. And I wonder if the classical limit of a particle path will become curved due to nearby holes. This might result in the curvature of general relativity. So I wonder if there has been any study on this.

Comment: You can formally "write down" the path integral on any space you like. I don't know what specific thing you might want to know about this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov–Bohm_effect - the solenoid excludes the path of an electron. So, the effective space has a cylindrical hole in it, just like you ask. So, the space is topologically non-trivial, and has the set of integers as its fundamental group. This is very important in explaining the Aharonov-Bohm effect; you can try to reproduce the effect in the path integral formalism (a professor did this in a lecture in grad school - very cool!)

Comment: For a simple point being removed, rather than a 1D line, I have a vague memory that this is related to magnetic monopoles.